# Determining where the Url should be splitted in C# MVC 4 route mapping

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, routes

I am mapping this route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "VotePage",
    "{category}/{medicine}/{id}-{condition}",
    new { controller = "Reactions", action = "Test" } 
);
```

However when I have an url after the last slash like this:
"/8438-this-is-a-test-condition"
Than the parameters are set like this:
id = 8438-this-is-a-test
condition = condition

Whilst the correct result should be:
id = 8438
condition = this-is-a-test-condition

How to split/seperate the url on the first dash?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, this should work

```
String foo = "/8438-this-is-a-test-condition";

if(foo.StartsWith("/")
{
    foo = foo.Split('/')[1];
}
```

EDIT:
.... no I did not understand you correctly. Sorry about that, i'll read more carefully next time.

I'm not sure how to achief what you ask for. I'd probebly just go for some find and replace magic, not pretty but it works....

Comment: I'm not able to alter the string this way when mapping a route. I'm more looking for a RegEx kind of solution. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Not acceptable to do it this way?

```
"{category}/{medicine}/{id}/{condition}"
```

Comment: It is possible, but you know those SEO guys...
And we dont have a page for "{category}/{medicine}/{id}/" so that means that people cannot browse pages by altering the Url, which we would like to keep.